# Cannot solved both using thenReturn or doReturn, any recommendation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

This code on ServiceImpl

```
List<EmployeeResponse> employeeResponses = employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(apiSecret, List.of(operationUserId));

Long branchId = Long.parseLong(employeeResponses.get(0).getWorklocationCode());
```

and, I wanna create the unit test, I already create this,

```
List<EmployeeResponse> employeeResponses = List.of(mockEmployeeResponse());
Long branchId = Long.parseLong(employeeResponses.get(0).getWorklocationCode());
```

and, when I use this,

```
doReturn(List.of(branchId)).when(employeeApiClient).getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList());
```

the response is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when I use this,

```
doReturn(branchId).when(employeeApiClient).getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList());
```

the response is

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Long cannot be returned by getEmployeeByEmpNo()
getEmployeeByEmpNo() should return List
```

and, when I use this,

```
when(employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList())).thenReturn(branchId);
```

the response is

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(Long)'
```

Maybe, any others way to solve this issue, thank you for help.

I'm new on use the unit test (Mock), so I tried to ask about my problem for learning and getting answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right and since `employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo` is returning `List<EmployeeResponse>` you should return the same type

```
when(employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList())).thenReturn(List.of(mockEmployeeResponse()));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your method in `when()` parameter is return a List of EmployeeResponse, you should put a List of EmployeeResponse too as argument in `.thenReturn()` parameter.

example:

```
List<EmployeeResponse> employeeResponses = List.of(mockEmployeeResponse());
when(employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList())).thenReturn(employeeResponses);
```

but if you want it return `Long` type, you can change when argument to:

```
Long exampleBranchId = 2L;
when(employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(any(), anyList()).get(anyInt()).getWorklocationCode()).thenReturn(exampleBranchId);
```